# What algorithms Splunk use for password encryption

Tags: splunk

Please help me to restore or change my Splunk enterprise password. I forgot Splunk username and password and I don't want to reinstall it cause I am having my data on it. So please help me to crack it. I tried all available ways which I got in google search, But nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

Splunk doesn't disclose their encryption algorithm.
There is an established procedure for "recovering" the admin password.  Stop Splunk and rename the $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/passwd file.  Start Splunk and sign in using the default password.  Change your password.  If you have no other users, you are done.  If you do have other users, stop Splunk, copy the encrypted password from $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/passwd to the passwd file you renamed earlier.  Put the renamed file back in its original name and location, then start Splunk.